# Encrypted R Markdown HTML file not displaying graphs?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, password-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt an HTML file that I'm creating using RMarkdown.  I'm using the `encryptedRmd` package.

For the markdown document, I have:

```
title: "My_Markdown"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
    self_contained: yes

 #ggplots below
```

And, converting this markdown to encrypted version:

```
library(encryptedRmd)

path = '//R_Scripts/My_Markdown.html'

encrypt_html_file(
  path,
  output_path = paste0(path, ".enc.html")
)
```

The encryption works, and I can access the new encrypted HTML.  However, none of the ggplots show up in the encrypted version, nor does the table of contents. Tables with data do show up. The test.html document has ggplots that appear, so I'm wondering why it's not translating to the encrypted version?

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of encryptRmd package, but looks interesting. when creating the .Rmd, what if you used `self_contained: yes` in the yaml? This will render the entire document to be self contained, hoping it will have good results for you

```
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: yes
```

I just tried it both ways and I was able to get the ggplot2 to display in both ways.

```
encrypt_html_file("//R_Scripts/test.html", "//R_Scripts/test_enc.html"))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  Unfortunately, the self_contained argument did not work.  I edited my question above.  What's odd is that both ggplots AND the table of contents do not show up.

Comment: For example, putting this in the yaml will fail to show a table of contents:                   
title: "test"
output: encryptedRmd::encrypted_html_document
toc: true
toc_float: true
toc_depth: 2
self_contained: yes